# Why, in Swift, when I convert from a Double to an Int is it subtracting 1?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some very simple code that does a calculation and converts the resulting double to an int.

```
let startingAge = (Double(babyAge/2).rounded().nextDown)
print(startingAge)

      for each in 0..<allQuestions.count {
                if allQuestions[each] == "\(Int(startingAge))"
```

The first print of startingAge gives me the correct answer, for example 5.0. But when it converts to an Int, it gives me an answer of 4. When the Double is 6.0, the int is 5.

I'm feeling stupid, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `rounded()`, you round your value to the nearest integer.

When you call `.nextDown`, you get the next possible value less than the existing value, which means you now have the highest value that's *less* than the nearest integer to your original value. This still displays as the integer when you print it, but that's just rounding; it's really slightly less than the integer. So if it's printing as "4.0", it's really something like 3.9999999999999 or some such.

When you convert the value to an `Int`, it keeps the integer part and discards the part to the right of the decimal. Since the floating-point value is slightly less than the integer you rounded to thanks to `.nextDown`, the integer part is going to be one less than that integer.

Solution: Get rid of the `.nextDown`.

Comment: I had no idea converting a value to an Int just discarded the part to the right of the decimal, so it made my rounding pointless. Therefore you saying that solved my problem! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

**When you cast you lose precession.**

In your case the line returns a double: Assume baby age is 9 then startingAge is 3.999999

```
let startingAge = (Double(babyAge/2).rounded().nextDown)
```

and when you print it your answer becomes 3

```
print("\(Int(startingAge))")
```

To fix this use this line instead:

```
let startingAge = (Double(babyAge/2).rounded().nextDown).rounded()
```

[image]

This is what nextdown does, it does not round values, and if the number is
a floating point number it becomes slightly less. If the number was to be an int it would become 1 less I presume.

[image]

Comment: What's the point of calling `.nextDown` and then rounding again? You're just going to end up with the same value that you got when you rounded the first time.

Comment: The Docs says this: The greatest representable value that compares less than this value.

Comment: Yes, and then when you round it again, it's going to go back to exactly what it was before you called `.nextDown`. So why bother calling it in the first place?

Comment: I have updated my answer, to illustrate what nextDown does.

Comment: I'm not asking what `.nextDown` does; if you look at my answer, you can see I'm quite aware of that. I'm questioning *why you want to use it here.* Basically, when you do `.rounded().nextDown.rounded()`, well, let's say the original value is 3.5. So: 1) we round that to 4: 2) we bring that slightly down to something like 3.999999: 3) we round that *back* to 4. At this point you may as well have it do the Hokey Pokey and turn itself around. This is a waste of computational resources. Just round the thing once and be done with it.